# How to append \ in strings?

Tags: c#, string

I have tried something like this

```
  string path= Server.MapPath("~") + "color\";
```

But its throwing an error

> "New line in constant"

Is there any way to append `"\"` in a string ?

Comment: What error? Just saying "thowing an error" is incredibly vague.

Comment: @DanielKelley:thanks for your feedback I have updated the question with error details

Comment: You might want to ask if you really need the \ at the end of the path string.  If you get in the habit of always using `Path.Combine` then you don't have to worry about the path delimiter.

Comment: This question shows a lack of research on the author's part.  This a basic problem of not using escape characters.

Comment: @Ramhound Cut him some slack. Maybe he never heard of escaping. Would you know how/where to search for a solution to "New line in constant" if you never heard of escaping?

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus - Have you done a google search on `new line in constant` recently? This just happens to be the second result: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/40160

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a verbatim string literal

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + @"color\";
```

or `\\`

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\";
```

The problem is that `\` escapes the closing `"`, that's why this doesn't work:

```
string invalid = "color\"; // same as: "color;
```

However, you should really use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class and it's methods if you're building paths as  [codingbiz has already mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279110/284240). It will make your code more readable and less error-prone

Comment: It's a good answer but I believe that the best one if @codingbiz's one because it makes use of `Path` class.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: yes, it's good to use the `Path` class in general. However, the question was `"how to append \ in string"`, so the focus is on the exception, why it happens and how to prevent it. Note that it's not path-specific and `Path.Combine` would not prevent the exception.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes that's what matters first - solving the OP's problem at hand. And later suggesting alternatives.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Tim was right too. My was extra stuff - may be needed

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, but it's nice to show to code better in addition to solve the whole problem :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Point taken. Edited my answer to point to the fact that using `Path` is always better when fiddling around with paths ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~") + @"color\");
```

OR

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\");
```

Path.Combine will make sure the path character "\" are inserted where missing

Answer (score 3):

use `@`, verbatim string,

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + @"color\";
```

or double the `\`

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\";
```

Or

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + @"color\";
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape it with another one.

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@` verbtaim in your string;

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + @"color\";
```

or use `\\` without verbtaim;

```
string path= Server.MapPath("~") + "color\\";
```

Check out [`String literals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from MSDN.